# What is the use of the .\ while executing python code in powershell

Tags: python, powershell

i saw someone do this in a video
suppose i have a python code called code.txt and i executed it using this command in powershell

```
python .\code.txt
```

what is the use of the `.\` here
it also happens to work with `./`

Comment: It's the path of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a notation referring to the current directory.

`python .\code.txt`, `python ./code.txt` and `python code.txt` produce the same result, as your file needs to be in current cmd/shell directory to be run this way. Or else you could execute it outside current cmd/shell directory specifying the full path, as `python C:\Users\Desktop\code.txt`.